# How to solve the Misra Warning about applying bitwise operators ~ and << for underlying type

Tags: c, embedded, misra

I have the following statement

```
CAN0_CTL_R &= ~ CAN_CTL_INIT;
```

and the required misra warning:

> If the bitwise operators ~ and << are applied to an operand of underlying type unsigned char or unsigned short, the result shall be immediately cast to the underlying type of the operand

the registers is defined as the following:

```
#define CAN_CTL_INIT            0x00000001U  // Initialization
#define CAN0_CTL_R              (*((volatile uint32_t *)0x40040000U))
```

since there is no short or char datatype, what is causing the warning?

Comment: which MISRA checker did you use ?

Comment: at least for the TI compilers, this has been confirmed as a false positive : https://e2e.ti.com/support/development_tools/compiler/f/343/t/236707

Comment: This is a valid question properly tagged MISRA. What you see is a consequence of D.6 (Appendix D, Essential types); by D.6, CAN_CTL_INIT has an essential type of `uint8_t`, so by MISRA, ~CAN_CTL_INIT could result 0xFF. The warning indicates that you should cast the result to this type (`uint8_t`) to make this outcome deterministic, that is, eliminating the consequence of integer promotion. The rule protects from errors relating to compilers with different int sizes. Your intent there is likely to get 0xFFFFFFFE from that complement, which wouldn't happen if the compiler had 16 bit ints.

Comment: @Jubatian: `0x1U` has a type of `unsigned int`, not `uint8_t` (i.e. `unsigned char`), not `unsigned short`. Please read the underlying **C** standard!

Comment: @toohonestforthissite The warning is according to the MISRA guide, not the C standard, which is important here. I meant that by the MISRA guide, see D.6, D.3 and D.1, which (again, by the guide, not the C standard) established unsigned char for this literal. Their reasoning is to eliminate cross-platform issues with integer promotion.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell the warning does not apply to the statement you present, given the macro definitions you say apply.  I speculate, however, that it is related to the integer constant `0x00000001U`.  Interpreted as an integer constant, that has type `unsigned int`, but it is possible that the MISRA tool misinterprets it as having a narrower type because its value would fit in a narrower one.

I suggest reducing the likelihood of machine or human misinterpretation by specifying the type explicitly:

```
#define CAN_CTL_INIT            ((unsigned int) 0x00000001U)  // Initialization
```

or

```
#define CAN_CTL_INIT            ((uint32_t) 0x00000001U)  // Initialization
```

.  The former yields an expression of the same type and value as the original on every conforming C implementation.  The latter is probably equivalent for you, and you may prefer it stylistically.  (And if the latter happens *not* to be equivalent for you, then you should consider whether it's actually what you wanted.)

Comment: The MISRA tool is correct here, MISRA-C-2012, Appendix D (Essential Types), D.6 defines the rule to apply here. The essential type of CAN_CTL_INIT is `uint8_t`, and it would truly produce a bug if the poster expected the complement to result 0xFFFFFFFE, and compiled with a compiler having 16 bits int size (where it would result 0xFFFE). Of course this wouldn't happen as this particular case is clearly hardware-specific, but otherwise the intent of the MISRA rule is a protection against such errors.

Comment: @Jubatian:according to the code shown, the **macro** `CAN_CTL_INIT` evaluates to (macros don't have a type) `0x00000001U` which is an `unsigned int`. `uint8_t`.can never have the type `unsigned int`, nor `unsigned short`. So, no, it does not apply here. The complement does not change the type and is well defined for unsigned. I agree the number of bits depends on the implementation, but `unsigned int` can never have less than 16 bit.